# Calculate difference between rows in Access

Tags: ms-access, rows, difference

The table looks like this:

```
part  value   
BAC    102  
BS1    275  
MAV    425  
BAC    519  
BSF    653  
BAC   1072
```

The result would be:

For part BAC

```
part  value  difference   
BAC    102       102  
BAC    519       417  
BAC   1072       553
```

There aren't any relations except value is in order.

The following SQL statement was used, but the result is useless because the result it doesn't filter by part as "WHERE" asks, and the first line should have the value of difference 102 but it's empty.

```
 SELECT ABS(T2.value - T1.value) AS Difference, T1.Part,T1.value,  
 FROM table AS T1 RIGHT JOIN table AS T2 ON 
 T2.report = T1.Report+ 1
 WHERE (((T1.part)=[Forms]![Parts]![Part]));
```

UPDATE:

I added to the function of @Tom Collins

```
Function GetDiff(CurrPart As String, CurrValue As Long) As Long  
Static LastPart As String  
Static LastValue As Long  
   If CurrPart <> LastPart Then  
      LastValue = 0  
      LastPart = CurrPart  
   End If  
   If LastValue = CurrValue Then  
   GetDiff = CurrValue  
   Else  
   GetDiff = CurrValue - LastValue  
   LastValue = CurrValue  
   End If  
End Function
```

Conclusions:
It comes out that the function works all right, but it happens a strange thing when the results are placed in a report, the first value of the query comes out wrong and when it's clicked it comes out right. Also another strange thing is, if I want an average for the field with the wrong value displayed, it displays the correct average and if I click on the wrong value that turns all right the average remains the same.
The question has been answered and the remaining problem is another question. 
Thank You @Tom Collins.

Comment: Where do 417 and 553 come from and what have you attempted, which part of SQL syntax are you having trouble with?

Comment: Difference 519-102 and 1072-519. The problem is that the first line doesn't give me the number 102. It's empty.

Answer (score 0):

OK, a brand new answer that strait SQL.

```
SELECT parts.id,
       parts.part,
       parts.value1,
       [value1] - Nz(Dmax("value1", "parts", "(value1 <" & [value1] &
                                             ") and (part = '" & [part]
                                                        &
                                                           "')"), 0) AS Diff
FROM   parts;
```

The **DMax** function returns the previous value *(the largest value that less than the current value, and where the part is the same)*, and the **Nz** function returns 0 if there is no previous value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it does what it should with one exception. The difference cell where should be 102 is the difference between 102-1072 (-970), which is not right.

Comment: Actually it's something odd happening. For the first run of the function results are good, but the second run of the function has the behavior previously presented.

Comment: I've added a WHERE clause
     WHERE (((Parts.Part)=[Forms]![Parts]![Part]))
and it gives me the first time the correct value and any other time -970

Comment: Yes, actually the data is sent to a report and if the user refreshes the report, it changes the result.

Comment: It's working, but i have a problem getting the values in the report. It display the wrong value for the first value, as we talked about, but if I get an average for the three values it comes out OK. The first value for average is 102 not -970. So why it shows the wrong value if it uses the good one ?

Comment: Yes, I used the other variable dummy and i understand the working of the function, but then again, I think it's not a matter of the query but something happening in the report side.  Also in the report if I click on the wrong value, it turns to the right value, but only by clicking once on that value, if I click on other values everything turns to garbage.

Comment: If I use the Select statement in a Query the results come out OK. If I use the statement in control source of a report the results are not good. The same if I use the query in the control source.

Comment: OK, found a better solution. It's strait SQL and doesn't use VBA. I think you'll like it. I also deleted my previous comments since they referred to my previous answer, so as to not confuse others who may read this later.